# Activity raises RAM use every time it is started

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, lifecycle

Alright, so i am sort of confused/frustrated.

I have a service that is always running and an activity. Every time the activity is launched and closed the App memory or ram use raises.

All i have in the activity are images and a seekbar.

What would i need to do to stop this as it could very quickly build up!

I also have alot of getter and setters. Such as tv.getText().toString(); and bg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);

---

So, in my onCreate it starts the ID's for the layouts and etc... every time the activity is created the memory or ram used will significantly raise. Is it duplicating the resources or something? It goes up at a constant rate.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);
    tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    //DATE & TIME STATS
    DateLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.DateLayout);
    curhour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hourText);
    curmin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minText);
    curmonth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthText);
    curday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dayText);
    curactualday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actualdayText);
    batt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.batt);

    //updateClock();

    //PATHS & TARGETS
    SliderUnlockPath = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider_unlock_path);
    SliderTextAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) SliderUnlockPath.getDrawable();

    //SLIDER
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //SliderUnlockPath.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockscreen_slider_path_light);
        SliderUnlockPath.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //SliderUnlockPath.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockscreen_slider_path);

        //IF RIGHTMOST (UNLOCK ZONE)
        int UnlockZone = seekbar.getProgress();
        if (UnlockZone > 86) UnlockZone = 100; {
            seekbar.setProgress(UnlockZone);
            SliderUnlockPath.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);                    
        } 
        if (UnlockZone == 100) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            finish();

        }

        //IF NOT RIGHTMOST
        int ResetZone = seekbar.getProgress();
        if (ResetZone < 86) ResetZone = 0; {
            seekbar.setProgress(ResetZone);
            SliderUnlockPath.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            SliderUnlockPath.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            //SliderUnlockPath.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockscreen_slider_path);
        }
    }
    });




    //WIDGETZONE VIEWFLIPPER
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.layoutswitcher);


    //MUSIC
    //MusicLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MusicLayout);
    //MusicInfoLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MusicInfoLayout);
    //UpdateMusicOnStart();


    //WEATHER
    WeatherTop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WeatherTop);
    WeatherTopAnimation();

    iconCurrent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iconcurrent);
    CurrentLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);
    CurrentHigh = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentHigh);
    CurrentCondition = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentCondition);
    //CurrentLow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentLow);

    //Get Location from Main Panel
    CurrentLocation.setText(place);

    //STRINGS FOR TEXT INFO
    //String weatherString = QueryGoogleWeather(place);
    //Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);
    /*if(parseGoogleWeather(weatherDoc)){
        //Display Result
        String c = currentConditions.condition
                + currentConditions.temp_f
                + currentConditions.temp_c;*/
                //+ currentConditions.humidity
                //+ currentConditions.wind_condition;

        //textCurrent.setText(c);

        /*textInfo.setText("city: " + forecastInformation.city + "\n"
        + "postal code: " + forecastInformation.postal_code + "\n"
        + "forecast date: " + forecastInformation.forecast_date + "\n"
        + "current date time: " + forecastInformation.current_date_time + "\n"
        + "unit: " + forecastInformation.unit_system);*/

    //CurrentLocation.setText(forecastInformation.city);

        //if (iLockerMain.TEMPSCALE.isChecked()) {
            //CurrentHigh.setText(currentConditions.temp_f+"°"+"F");
        //} else {
            //CurrentHigh.setText(currentConditions.temp_c+"°"+"C");
        //}

        //CurrentCondition.setText(currentConditions.condition);

        //Bitmap bm = LoadIcon(currentConditions.icon);
        //iconCurrent.setImageBitmap(bm);

    /*if (CurrentCondition.getText().toString().equals("Overcast")) {
            iconCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cloudy3small);
        } else if (CurrentCondition.getText().toString().equals("Light rain")) {
            iconCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_rainsmall);
        } else if (CurrentCondition.getText().toString().equals("Light snow")) {
            iconCurrent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow3small);
        }*/



    mHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    //updateClock();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);


    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    //unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Unclosed / undisposed handles to images or variables probably - what language?

Comment: Hard to know without seeing any hard code...

Comment: "Every time the activity is launched and closed the App memory or ram use raises." -- you neglected to explain how you determined this. Use DDMS and MAT to examine your heap and see if you are leaking something.

Comment: if i look in the running apps with in manage apps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing all your allocations in onDestroy()?